# How to track iPhone App installs and referrer

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there any way to track the iPhone App installs and referrer whithout using any third party like appflyer etc..

I would like to track if any user installs the app by clicking on appstore url.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call your own web-service when the user first launches your application and pass along the identifierForVendor.  You could then store the date and that id to track how many installs you have and when the install took place.  Use NSUserDefaults to store a BOOL (NSNumber) indicating the web-service has been called.

Comment: This works if I only want to track the installs irrespective of campaign or referrer. I would like to track from which campaign the install has happend.

Comment: Not gonna be possible unless you also ask the user on first app launch which campaign or referrer they came from.

Comment: You can use device fingerprinting to be able to tell the source for each user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378063/how-to-track-iphone-app-installs-and-referrer

Comment: 6 years later, is there a solution for this? with storekit and appstore search ads...?